# Partially apply the tuple function using List.map

Tags: f#

Given a function that takes two arguments:

```
let f (a:int) (b:int) : string = sprintf "%d %d" a b
```

And a list of tuples:

```
let myList = [(1,2) ; (3,3)]
```

How do I partially apply the tuple operator `(||>)` using a map?

```
myList |> List.map ((||>) f)            //doesn't work
myList |> List.map (fun x -> (||>) x f) //boring
```

It seems like I need to reverse the arguments that `||>` needs.

Comment: Is ||> a custom operator?  I don't see it in the F# symbol and operator reference at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx

Comment: @MarkPattison that is a built-in operator `('a * 'b -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'c)`

Comment: @Mark : See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340237.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
myList |> List.map ((<||) f)
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, using `(<||)` as @desco did is the shortest answer. You can easily write in point-free style using `uncurry`:

```
let inline uncurry f (x, y) = f x y
myList |> List.map (uncurry f)
```

or even more bizarre with built-in functions:

```
myList |> List.map ((|>) f << (||>))
```

Proof:

```
(|>) f << (||>)
<=> fun x -> ((|>) f << (||>)) x
<=> fun x -> ((|>) f) ((||>) x)
<=> fun x -> (|>) f ((||>) x)
<=> fun x -> f |> ((||>) x)
<=> fun x -> (||>) x f
```